# MATLAB: Checking for identical columns, and adding noise to make them non-identical

Tags: matlab

I have a MATLAB double array (usually 3x151, but the size may change), and I want to check if any of the columns have the exact same values in them in the same order.

For example, in the following array Columns 1 and 2 are duplicates, but Column 3 is not.

```
[ 3    3    2 ; 
  2    2    2 ;
  2    2    3 ]
```

If duplicate columns are found, I want to add a small amount of noise (presumably to one of the columns only) to ensure that they are no longer duplicates.

What's the most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Reading the other answer I noticed your question talks about duplicate columns but your example data contains duplicate rows 1 and 2. It might be that my answer does it wrong way round, please clarify your question.

Comment: Another way of finding dublicates could be pdist of a transposed matrix, but it depends on the size of the matrix you have

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you have to identify the duplicate columns. Most efficient way is using `unique` which gives you the opposite in two ways, a list of unique rows. Use transpose and setdiff to get duplicate columns:

```
M=[ 3    3    2;    2    2    2;   2    2    3];
[~,unique_cols,~]=unique(M.','rows');
duplicate_cols=setdiff(1:size(M,2),unique_cols);
```

Now having the duplicate columns identified, generate noise and add it:

```
M(:,duplicate_cols)=M(:,duplicate_cols)+rand(size(M,1),numel(duplicate_cols));
```

If  you want to be 100% sure to get unique values, run the code until `unique_rows` is empty. By very bad luck rand might repeat values, but for your small data set that will probably never happen.

Comment: Very nice. Definitely better than the nested loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if two columns are equal using [isequal](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isequal.html) and add the noise e.g. using [rand](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html?searchHighlight=rand).

For you example, you can compare each column with each other using

```
s = size(A,2); % Number of columns

for i1 = 1:s-1
    for i2 = i1+1:s
        if isequal(A(:,i1),A(:,i2))
            A(:,i2) = A(:,i2)+rand(size(A(:,i2)))/100;
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Another Solution, based on Daniel's answer, could be the use of jitter(...) function that you can find on Matlab Central (see this [link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10425-jitter))

Follow Daniel's process for identifying the duplicate cols

```
M=[ 3    3    2;    2    2    2;   2    2    3];
[~,unique_cols,~]=unique(M.','rows');
duplicate_cols=setdiff(1:size(M,2),unique_cols);
```

And next, use the `jitter(...)` function as follows:

```
M(:,duplicate_cols)=jitter(M(:,duplicate_cols))
```

for adding predefined noise.

This function can be adjusted with following options:

1. factor,
2. uniformOrGaussianFlag,
3. smallOrRangeFlag,
4. realOrIm